# How to get version number of another application?

Tags: android

I'm trying to listen for updates to apps that aren't my own. You can listen for intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and use the uid to get the app name like so:

```
PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
    String name = manager.getNameForUid(uid);
```

Is there any way to get that app's version number? I've looked through the PackageManager methods and couldn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That information is part of [`PackageInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html) (`versionCode` and `versionName`).

You can get that via the [`PackageManager.getPackageInfo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method